# Determining connection options of a different connection in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know if there is a way to determine what another connection's options are from the server?  I have a query that is running very nicely in SSMS however when it runs through ADO.NET, it runs horribly slowly and I suspect that some kind of setting on the connection like ARITHABORT is different between the two.  Unfortunately this problem is in a production machine so I can't just crack the code and throw in some diagnostics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in `sys.dm_exec_sessions` for the pertinent `session_id`

Columns include `quoted_identifier, arithabort, ansi_null_dflt_on, ansi_defaults, ansi_warnings,ansi_padding, ansi_nulls, concat_null_yields_null`

Comment: @JNK - Yes. I don't have a SQL Server 2000 instance around to test if this is available somewhere`

Answer (score 0):

you could try the SQL Sever Profiler.